# Best way to save all the data info onPause

Tags: java, android

i'm making an app and i'd like to create option to pause the app activity and move to another activity which will allow to go back and resume the game
My app is built of a class contacting few vars and some other smaller classes, and i was wondering what is the best way to save all this data to get it back onResume and continue the game?
Game built of:

```
public class snake {
    int[][] board;
    part head;
    LinkedList<part> full = new LinkedList<part>();
    box box ;
    int count;
    int currx,curry;
}
```

Comment: you need to put data on bundle object

Answer (score 0):

When your activity loses focus, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called. This is the place to save your state:

```
private static final String GAME_STATE_KEY = "game_state";

private snake state;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        

    outState.putSerializable(GAME_STATE_KEY, state);
}
```

When the user navigates back to your activity, you can restore the state in `onCreate()`. See the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) for reference.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        state = (snake) savedInstanceState.getSeriazable(GAME_STATE_KEY);
    }
    else {
        state = new snake();
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need to make `snake` as well as your other custom classes it contains (`part`, `box`), `Serializable`. For example, `class snake implements Serializable`.

Comment: Dude, why Serializable instead of Parcelable?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Because it's easier. Implementing `Parcelable` requires more effort and time and for this case, it doesn't make sense, as a small amount of data need to be serialized.

Comment: It says "Cannot resolve method 'put(java.lang.String , com.example.pc.snake.snake)' on  outState.put(GAME_STATE_KEY, state) any ideawhy?

Comment: @user3710700 Sorry ,it was `putSerializable()`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: For some reason after i click resume on the other activity , and go back to this activity it still goes to the onCreate and creates new class , how can i avoid it?

Comment: So add it to the answer, cause Google standards says to use Parcelable.

Comment: @user3710700 I have updated the answer to use `onCreate()` to check for the saved state so it's easier to restore the state. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to store the Data in bundle form in android:

- shared preference in android save the make a new bundle for and save the current state in `onStart()` method and restore in `onResume()`
- saved the state in *onSaveInstanceState*

these methods are working for a orientation in android. I think this is working:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);   
    }
```

Comment: How do i save the data in a bundle form in android and then restore it back?

Comment: yes it is possible because  of according to activity life cycle activity one is on onPause () state and the go back to second  activity  to activity one is OnResume()  method is call.

Comment: I tried to use the code you wrote , but it doesn't seem to work do i need to make any changes so it will work? because it creates the activity as new activity and no information is restored

Comment: bro for you also need to change a code according to the required I will given you are just a idea.please given me the full code I will update you accoding to you requirement

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways you can use:

SQLite , SharedPreferences , FileInput and FileOutput Streams, And Maybe just a Simple Intent In OnPause of your Activity That you Want to Save.

Try This Simple Intent FLags:

```js
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
OR
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Then use
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

AS LONG AS YOU'RE INSIDE THE APP TRY TO AVOID SAVING ANYTHING, Use SharedPreferences Instead, Save when Only The App is Being Closed Or Destroyed